# Laravel table is showing unique id multiple times

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project am taking data from multiple tables and showing it in view.

I have uploaded the picture of current output.

[image]

I have multiple services in one location id, but I want to show only one location id and their corresponding services in right side.

Following is my code in **controller**

```
public function showClinicLocations($id)
    {
        $clinic = Clinic::find($id);
        $locations = Location::where('clinicID', $id)->get();
        $locationservices = Service::select('services.serviceName as servicename','locations.locationID as locid') 
        ->join('location_services', 'location_services.serviceID', '=', 'services.serviceID')
        ->join('locations', 'locations.locationID', '=', 'location_services.locationID') 
        ->join('clinics', 'clinics.clinicID', '=', 'locations.clinicID') 
        ->where('clinics.clinicID','=',$id) 
        ->get();
        return view('clinic.locations')->with(['locations' =>  $locations  ,'clinic'=>$clinic , 'services'=> $locationservices]);
    }
```

Following is the code in **view page**

```
<table>
                                       <thead>
                                           <tr>
                                               <th>Location Name</th>
                                               <th>Services</th>
                                           </tr>
                                       </thead>
                                       <tbody>
                                       @foreach($services as $service)
                                           <tr>
                                               <td>{!! $service->locid !!}</td>
                                               <td>{!! $service->servicename !!}</td>
                                           </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                       </tbody>
                                   </table>
```

I want to show only one unique locid and their services in one row, why am not getting like that

And my expected output is in given image

[image]

Comment: you mean you want to get in one locid many services in one row??

Comment: yes, i need like that

Comment: how do you want the result will be? do you want it to have a comma seperated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are retrieving from database as the output you show, you can achieve what you want by just changing your blade template like this:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($locations as $location)
  <tr>
    <?php 
        $first = true;
        foreach($services as $service){
            echo('<tr>')
            if($service->locid == $location->locationID ){
                if($first){
                    echo('<td class="first">' . $location->locationID . '</td>')
                    $first=false;
                }
                else{
                    echo('<td class="second"></td>')
                }
                echo('<td>'.$service->servicename.'</td>') 
                echo('<td><button id="btn_'.$service->serviceID.'">Delete</button></td>')
            }
            echo('</tr>')
        }
    ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

To erase the lines, you'll have to add some CSS:

```
.first{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.second{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Now no data  is displaying

Comment: I changed the location id, because I saw you named it different, try again now

Comment: It works , now all the services in one location is showing in one line, how can i use it in line by line format

Comment: I think I don't get what you mean with line by line, could you add to your question an example of how you want it?

Comment: if loc id 53 have multiple serives A and B,  Now it is showing as 53 Service A Service B , i want it as service A , service b . Means comma seperated or like             service a                                                                                                                     service b (service b must be in under of service a)

Comment: okay, I edited the first code, now it should be separated by commas

Comment: Bro , can i get it one under to another one format, anyway thanks a lot brother

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209059/discussion-between-gamopo-and-xavier-issac).

Answer (score 0):

As of now your query result will be separated because you didn't group them.

**Here's example**

```
        $locationservices = Service::select(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(services.serviceName SEPERATOR ',') as servicename, locations.locationID as locid") 
        ->join('location_services', 'location_services.serviceID', '=', 'services.serviceID')
        ->join('locations', 'locations.locationID', '=', 'location_services.locationID') 
        ->join('clinics', 'clinics.clinicID', '=', 'locations.clinicID') 
        ->where('clinics.clinicID','=',$id) 
        ->groupBy('locations.locationID')
        ->get();
```

If group by has an error just add the servicename

```
        ->groupBy('locations.locationID', 'services.serviceName')
```

then the view is just the same.

You can change the seperator anything you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by that? its still eloquent format with raw.

Comment: You need the raw on other function of sql because its still not supported in laravel.